# Rendering template via AJAX in Grails

Tags: jquery, grails

I have the following code in an action

```
    render ( template: 'partial_list_template', model: [messageList: entries, totalFound: count, activeUILink: "all_mgs_link", termFreqs: null])
```

I have the following code in the gsp page

```
$j("#filterUpdate").click(function(event){

        var form = $j('#flags');



         new Ajax.Request('/tabulae/webForm/filter',
                {
                onSuccess:function(resp){

                               console.log(resp.responseText);
                                console.log($j('#filterResults'))
                                $j('#filterResults').remove()
                                $j('#filterResults').innerHTML(resp.responseText)
                            },
                            onError: function(resp) {
                                alert("Error:" + resp.toJSON());
                                return;
                            },
                            asynchronous:true,
                            evalScripts:true,
                            method:'GET',
                            parameters:form.serialize()

                });
      });
```

even though I see the html  output in the console log. I don't see the html output in the element where I'm adding this content. Any ideas why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using `empty`

```
$j('#filterResults').empty();                            
  $j('#filterResults').innerHTML(resp.responseText);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I had tried empty and html before and for some reasons, it didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Do not use .**remove()** since then you will be removing the element and in the next step there is no element to be found. But also, there is no method called .**innerHTML()** ... you should be using .**html()**

Hope that helps